# badblocks found bad sectors on usb pen, how to mark these up so nothing will write on them

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

Got a 2TB usb pen, format to exfat and did a badblocks check,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo badblocks -vsw /dev/sda1 -o  /home/pi/badblocks.out
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 2047998958
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done
Reading and comparing: 100% done, 36:46:23 elapsed. (0/0/123073863 errors)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ head badblocks.out
28863552
28863553
28863554
28863555
28863556
28863557
28863558
28863559
28863560
28863561
...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail badblocks.out
151937405
151937406
151937407
151937408
151937409
151937410
151937411
151937412
151937413
151937414
```

Does this mean out of 2,047,998,958 blocks there are 123,073,863 blocks are bad?
2TB has 123MB bad blocks.

As I use badblocks -w, does the tool mark out the bad sectors so they won't be touched in future when copying data onto it? if not, what tool can do that?

Comment: Guess: Cheap Chinese USB stick that isn't really 2 TB, but a lower capacity (in particular if you have the whole range, which I can't see from head/tail). Simples solution: Make your partition smaller so it reflects the real size. I wouldn't mess with the badblocks table, it will be too big.

Comment: @dirkt; yes, assuming it was purchased at amazon or similar, 90% of those (conservative estimate) are fake similar to https://www.disktuna.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/FakeTBSSD.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As badblocks may do multiple test passes over the disk,
you should pass the list through `sort | uniq` in order to ensure that a block
is counted only once.

The `-w` mode specifies write-mode test. It does cause bad sectors to be marked.
Beware that this will put extra load on your disk which might cause it to fail,
since it doesn't look to be in very good shape.

In any case, using a disk that has so many bad sectors is not recommended.
On the other hand, there is no way to fix a bad pen disk.

My best recommendation is to avoid using this pen - it seems to be half dead,
and will only get worse.

Comment: This answer does not address the question: ways to mark as damaged the block.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Use write-mode.

Comment: That is not the behavior of "-w" : https://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: The OS marks hard errors encountered when writing, not badblocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your USB drive will probably a counterfeit device. It claims to be 2 TB but instead it will be way smaller than that. You can use a tool called "f3" (https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to check if thats the case. A `f3probe` will check if your drive is a fake or not. If it is a fake (and I'm quite sure it is), it will tell you the way to "fix" the issue with the right settings for the `f3fix` command. It comes down to creating a partition at the start of the disk with the size of the actual usable disk size.

Some background reading: https://datarecovery.com/2022/03/the-2tb-flash-drive-scam-why-high-capacity-flash-drives-are-fakes/